# Python: How to monitor status of multiple Python processes running in Windows Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, scheduler

I have several Python modules running under the Windows Scheduler (Windows Server 2008 R2).  I'd like to verify that they are active ('running') and haven't been inadvertently stopped.

```
 os.popen("tasklist").read()
```

Only tells me there are Python processes, it doesn't give me their status (running/ready/etc) or a way to ID which process it is.

Can someone assist, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html): a package in python to work with windows processes and other information. You can find some example [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html).

In your case you can do:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process ():
    print process.ProcessId, process.Name, process.Status
```

The list of all properties of Win32_Process is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) on Microsoft website.